# Knockout sortable makes duplicates (making a tree structure)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I am making a editable tree structure with Knockout sortable and found this great example: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Lqttf

That works fine, but I have a list of root nodes so I changed the root node binding to be a sortable list of tree items too. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yyqnhngm

The new template markup looks like this (notice that the root ul is a `sortable` binding and not a `template` as in the original):

```
<script id="nodeTmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a>
        <div>
           <ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: $data.children }"></ul>            
        </div>
    </li>
</script>

<ul data-bind="sortable: { template: 'nodeTmpl', data: root }"></ul>
```

If you drag B into A, then B will be *copied* instead of moved into A. That's the issue I'm looking for a cause of and solution to. My immediate thought is that sortable thinks the item is dragged into both the lists at the same time, maybe because of a markup/html issue, but I can't see how.

Note: I know I could just wrap all the items into a root note, but that doesn't make much sense for my purposes.

Comment: Doesn't the library require the items to sort to be in an `observableArray`? If I change the `root` array to a `ko.observableArray`, all _seems_ to work fine. From the docs: "knockout-sortable is a binding for Knockout.js designed to connect **observableArrays** with jQuery UI's sortable functionality"

Comment: I think you are correct, that seems to be it. If you could submit an answer I will mark it as the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that there's no support for "ordinary" arrays. Changing the array in your viewmodel to an `observableArray` gives you the required bahavior. I.e.:

```
ko.applyBindings({
  root: ko.observableArray([
    new TreeItem("A", []),
    new TreeItem("B", [])
  ])
});
```

For reference:

According to the [knockout-sortable readme](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) *(emphasis mine)*:

> knockout-sortable is a binding for Knockout.js designed to connect **observableArrays** with jQuery UI's sortable functionality.

I also tried to go through the source to be able to explain what exactly was going wrong, but couldn't find the exact cause. I did find a snippet which seems to at least explain the author's thoughts.

The code shows that the plugin's default behavior uses the `splice` method to move an element between arrays. This could explain why your example didn't trigger an exception: both `Array.prototype` and a `ko.observableArray` have a `splice` method; both take similar arguments.

The last comment in the code block explains that `targetParent` and `sourceParent` are expected to be observable.

```
if (!sortable.hasOwnProperty("strategyMove") || sortable.strategyMove === false) {
  //do the actual move
  if (targetIndex >= 0) {
    if (sourceParent) {
      sourceParent.splice(sourceIndex, 1);

      //if using deferred updates plugin, force updates
      if (ko.processAllDeferredBindingUpdates) {
        ko.processAllDeferredBindingUpdates();
      }
    }

    targetParent.splice(targetIndex, 0, item);
  }

  //rendering is handled by manipulating the observableArray; ignore dropped element
  dataSet(el, ITEMKEY, null);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/blob/master/src/knockout-sortable.js#L250